# Unexpected error while obtaining UI hierarchy java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException for android 8.1.0

Tags: java, user-interface, appium, android-uiautomator

In UIautomatorViewer unable to get a screenshot of Android 8.1.0 (MI note 5) and I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to obtain UI hierarchy.
>   Java.Lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExcepion.

Can someone please help me out in resolving this?

[image]

Comment: Is this only on a particular screen in the app?  Real device or emulator?  Have you tried simply restarting the UIAutomator (this error is common)  Are you running Appium Server (desktop) in the background (it can interfere).  More info needed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by updating my SDK Tools (25.x.x to 26.1.1) trought Android Studio. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to upadte beacuse i could not find any update in sdkmanager